# Masking in BERT

Tags: tensorflow, masking, bert-language-model

In the original paper of BERT it is said:

> Note that the purpose of the masking strategies
>   is to reduce the mismatch between pre-training
>   and fine-tuning, as the [MASK] symbol never appears during the fine-tuning stage.

Let's consider a sentence "I am a Liverpool fan" which with 40% masking will be transformed into "I [MASK] a [MASK] fan". When predicting the first [MASK], will it be predicted by a phrase "I [MASK] a fan", excluding the second [MASK] or "I [MASK] a [MASK] fan", by a full sentence?

And what is the purpose of replacing 10% of masked tokens with themselves? Does it mean they will not be predicted? Or we will predict them, having themselves in the context (like predicting the first [MASK] by "I am a [MASK] fan"?

Will be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the paper clearly, and also check out the paper on XLNET which explains the drawback of BERT, it implies that, given a sentence "I [MASK] a [MASK] fan", it tries to predict both the [MASK] tokens using the sentence "I [MASK] a [MASK] fan", and not "I [MASK] a Liverpool fan".

Due to this, it masks only 15% of the tokens. The idea behind retaining the 10% of the mask tokens as it is, implies that they will not be predicted.